# Zend Controller Action: _redirect() vs getHelper('Redirector')->gotoUrl()

Tags: zend-framework, redirect, zend-controller

I've read that `$this->getHelper('[helper_name]')` is preferable to `$this->_helper->[helper_name]`.  What I haven't been able to find any documentation of is which of these is better/preferred: `$this->_redirect($url)` or `$this->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoUrl($url)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use whatever one suits you, they do exactly the same thing:

```
/**
 * Redirect to another URL
 *
 * Proxies to {@link Zend_Controller_Action_Helper_Redirector::gotoUrl()}.
 *
 * @param string $url
 * @param array $options Options to be used when redirecting
 * @return void
 */
protected function _redirect($url, array $options = array())
{
    $this->_helper->redirector->gotoUrl($url, $options);
}
```

Comment: Interesting!  I looks like `getHelper()` isn't used internally.  I wonder why it's recommended.

Comment: @Sonny, it's not really not recommended; `_helper` is easier to type and read and is often preferred over the explicit `getHelper()` syntax. A benefit of using `getHelper()`, though, is that you automatically have intellisense support in your editor, where you would not have it when using the `_helper` magic getter. Personally, I prefer readability over intellisense, and use `_helper` :)

Comment: Also getHelper is complement to setHelper ;) Which can be IMO used to register Helpers with fancy prefixes you don't want to have in your helper search path...